# How Do I Make a Faster Riak MapReduce Query?

Tags: mapreduce, riak, riak-search

**How can we make our MapReduce Queries Faster?**

We have built an application using a five node Riak DB cluster. 
Our data model is composed of three buckets: matches, leagues, and teams.

Matches contains links to leagues and teams:

**Model**

```
var match = {
        id: matchId,
        leagueId: meta.leagueId,
        homeTeamId: meta.homeTeamId,
        awayTeamId: meta.awayTeamId,
        startTime: m.match.startTime,
        firstHalfStartTime: m.match.firstHalfStartTime,
        secondHalfStartTime: m.match.secondHalfStartTime,
        score: {
            goals: {
                a: 1*safeGet(m.match, 'score.goals.a'),
                b: 1*safeGet(m.match, 'score.goals.b')
            },
            corners: {
                a: 1*safeGet(m.match, 'score.corners.a'),
                b: 1*safeGet(m.match, 'score.corners.b')
            }
        }
    };

var options = {
        index: {
            leagueId: match.leagueId,
            teamId: [match.homeTeamId, match.awayTeamId],
            startTime: match.startTime || match.firstHalfStartTime || match.secondHalfStartTime
        },
        links: [
            { bucket: 'leagues', key: match.leagueId, tag: 'league' },
            { bucket: 'teams', key: match.homeTeamId, tag: 'home' },
            { bucket: 'teams', key: match.awayTeamId, tag: 'away' }
        ]
    };
    match.model = 'match';
    modelCache.save('matches', match.id, match, options, callback);
```

**Queries**

We write a query that returns results from several buckets, one way is to query each bucket separately. The other way is to use links to combine results from a single query.

Two versions of the query we tried both take over a second, no matter how small our bucket size.
The first version uses two map phases, which we modeled after this post ([Practical Map-Reduce: Forwarding and Collecting](http://basho.com/blog/technical/2010/04/14/practical-map-reduce:-forwarding-and-collecting/)).

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -X POST \
-H "content-type: application/json" \
-d @- \
http://localhost:8091/mapred \
<<EOF
{
    "inputs":{
        "bucket":"matches",
        "index":"startTime_bin",
        "start":"2012-10-22T23:00:00",
        "end":"2012-10-24T23:35:00"
    },
    "query": [
        {"map":{"language": "javascript", "source":"
                function(value, keydata, arg){
                    var match = Riak.mapValuesJson(value)[0];
                    var links = value.values[0].metadata.Links;
                    var result = links.map(function(l) {
                        return [l[0], l[1], match];
                    });
                    return result;
                }
            "}
        },
        {"map":{"language": "javascript", "source": "
                function(value, keydata, arg) {
                    var doc = Riak.mapValuesJson(value)[0];
                    return [doc, keydata];
                }
            "}
        },
        {"reduce":{
            "language": "javascript",
                "source":"
                    function(values) {
                        var merged = {};
                        values.forEach(function(v) {
                            if(!merged[v.id]) {
                                merged[v.id] = v;
                            }
                        });
                        var results = [];
                        for(key in merged) {
                            results.push(merged[key]);
                        }
                        return results;
                    }
                "
            }
        }
    ]
}
EOF
```

In the second version we do four separate Map-Reduce queries to get the objects from the three buckets:

```
async.series([
        //First get all matches
        function(callback) {
            db.mapreduce
                .add(inputs)
                .map(function (val, key, arg) {
                    var data = Riak.mapValuesJson(val)[0];
                    if(arg.leagueId && arg.leagueId != data.leagueId) {
                        return [];
                    }
                    var d = new Date();
                    var date = data.startTime || data.firstHalfStartTime || data.secondHalfStartTime;
                    d.setFullYear(date.substring(0, 4));
                    d.setMonth(date.substring(5, 7) - 1);
                    d.setDate(date.substring(8, 10));
                    d.setHours(date.substring(11, 13));
                    d.setMinutes(date.substring(14, 16));
                    d.setSeconds(date.substring(17, 19));
                    d.setMilliseconds(0);
                    startTimestamp = d.getTime();
                    var short = {
                        id: data.id,
                        l: data.leagueId,
                        h: data.homeTeamId,
                        a: data.awayTeamId,
                        t: startTimestamp,
                        s: data.score,
                        c: startTimestamp
                    };
                    return [short];
                }, {leagueId: query.leagueId, page: query.page}).reduce(function (val, key) {
                    return val;
                }).run(function (err, matches) {
                    matches.forEach(function(match) {
                        result.match[match.id] = match; //Should maybe filter this
                        leagueIds.push(match.l);
                        teamIds.push(match.h);
                        teamIds.push(match.a);
                    });
                    callback();
                });
        },
        //Then get all leagues, teams and lines in parallel
        function(callback) {
            async.parallel([
                //Leagues
                function(callback) {
                    db.getMany('leagues', leagueIds, function(err, leagues) {
                        if (err) { callback(err); return; }
                        leagues.forEach(function(league) {
                            visibleLeagueIds[league.id] = true;
                            result.league[league.id] = {
                                r: league.regionId,
                                n: league.name,
                                s: league.name
                            };
                        });
                        callback();
                    });
                },
                //Teams
                function(callback) {
                    db.getMany('teams', teamIds, function(err, teams) {
                        if (err) { callback(err); return; }
                        teams.forEach(function(team) {
                            result.team[team.id] = {
                                n: team.name,
                                h: team.name,
                                s: team.stats
                            };
                        });
                        callback();
                    });
                }
            ], callback);
        }
    ], function(err) {
        if (err) { callback(err); return; }
        _.each(regionModel.getAll(), function(region) {
           result.region[region.id] = {
               id: region.id,
               c: 'https://d1goqbu19rcwi8.cloudfront.net/icons/silk-flags/' + region.icon + '.png',
               n: region.name
           };
        });
        var response = {
            success: true,
            result: {
                modelRecords: result,
                paging: {
                    page: query.page,
                    pageSize: 50,
                    total: result.match.length
                },
                time: moment().diff(a)/1000.00,
                visibleLeagueIds: visibleLeagueIds
            }
        };
        callback(null, JSON.stringify(response, null, '\t'));
    });
```

How do we make these queries faster?

**Additional info:**

We are using riak-js and node.js to run our queries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to make it at least a bit faster would be to deploy the JavaScript mapreduce functions to the server instead of passing them through as part of the job. (see description of **js_source_dir** parameter [here](http://docs.basho.com/riak/1.2.0/references/Configuration-Files/)). This is usually recommended if you have a JavaScript functions that you run repeatedly.

As there is some overhead associated with running JavaScript mapreduce functions compared to native ones implemented in Erlang, using non-JavaScript functions where possible may also help.

The two map phase functions in your first query appear to be designed to work around the limitation that a normal linking phase (which I believe is more efficient) does not pass on the record being processed (the *matches* record). The first function includes all the links and passes on the match data as additional data in JSON form, while the second passes on the data of the match as well as the linked record in JSON form.

I have written a simple Erlang function that includes all links as well as the ID of the record passed in. This could be used together with the native Erlang function **riak_kv_mapreduce:map_object_value** to replace the two map phase functions in your first example, removing some of the JavaScript usage. As in the existing solution, I would expect you to receive a number of duplicates as several matches may link to the same league/team.

```
-module(riak_mapreduce_example).

-export([map_link/3]).

%% @spec map_link(riak_object:riak_object(), term(), term()) ->
%%                   [{{Bucket :: binary(), Key :: binary()}, Props :: term()}]
%% @doc map phase function for adding linked records to result set
map_link({error, notfound}, _, _) ->
    [];
map_link(RiakObject, Props, _) ->
    Bucket = riak_object:bucket(RiakObject),
    Key = riak_object:key(RiakObject),
    Meta = riak_object:get_metadata(RiakObject),
    Current = [{{Bucket, Key}, Props}],
    Links = case dict:find(<<"Links">>, Meta) of
        {ok, List} ->
            [{{B, K}, Props} || {{B, K}, _Tag} <- List];
        error ->
            []
    end,
    lists:append([Current, Links]).
```

The results of these can either be sent back to the client for aggregation or passed into a reduce phase function as in the example you provided.

The example function would need to be compiled and installed on all nodes, and may require a restart.

Another way to improve performance (that very well may not be an option for you) would perhaps be alter the data model in order to avoid having to use mapreduce queries for performance critical queries altogether.